# Catching JSON request parse errors and return 500 Response in JSON - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am writing a Rails API and want to catch any JSON parse error in the request and return a nicely formatted JSON with useful information. I have tried the following solution by adding a class to catch parse errors, referenced [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/catching-json-parse-errors-with-custom-middleware)

I have tried to remove the if statement that checks for JSON format in the ACCEPT header and it still doesn't work. I think the request isn't even hitting this middleware in the first place.

Any help would be appreciated. What would also be useful is how I should go about debugging this on my own. Thanks.

```
# in app/middleware/catch_json_parse_errors.rb
class CatchJsonParseErrors
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    begin
      @app.call(env)
    rescue ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError => error
      if env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] =~ /application\/json/
        error_output = "There was a problem in the JSON you submitted: #{error}"
        return [
          400, { "Content-Type" => "application/json" },
          [ { status: 400, error: error_output }.to_json ]
        ]
      else
        raise error
      end
    end
  end
end
```

application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Yomiapp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

    config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, "CatchJsonParseErrors"

    config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework :rspec, fixture: true
      g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: 'spec/factories'
      g.view_specs false
      g.helper_specs false
      g.stylesheets = false
      g.javascripts = false
      g.helper = false
    end

    config.autoload_paths += %W(\#{config.root}/lib)

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*',
          headers: :any,
          methods: [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :patch, :options],
          max_age: 0
      end
    end

    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
  end
end
```

rake middleware

```
use Rack::Cors
use ActionDispatch::Static
use Rack::Lock
use #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x000001040ce608>
use Rack::Runtime
use ActionDispatch::RequestId
use Rails::Rack::Logger
use ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
use ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
use ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
use ActionDispatch::Reloader
use ActionDispatch::Callbacks
use ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
use ActiveRecord::QueryCache
use CatchJsonParseErrors
use ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
use Rack::Head
use Rack::ConditionalGet
use Rack::ETag
use Warden::Manager
use ActionDispatch::Flash
run Yomiapp::Application.routes
```

Comment: run "rake middleware" on your console to check your middleware is properly inserted or not, and find "CatchJsonParseErrors" on the list.

Comment: @PardeepSaini thanks. I updated my `rake middleware` result above. You can see that CatchJsonParseErrors is right above use ActionDispatch::ParamsParser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only need to restart the server.The changes in application.rb effect only when you restart server. Now you stop the server to run rake middleware command and application.rb refreshed and start working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am not sure what happened but it's working now without any code change. I will update again if I figured out what went wrong.